# Easy for-loop in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem with my for-loop. I have never worked with either python or flask before. I want to iterate over a list and use the elements in it. The list looks like this:

```
NAVBAR_LIST = ["/", "Home", "/database/", "Database", "Log out"]
```

My code looks like this:

```
{% for topic in NAVBAR_LIST %}
    {{topic}}
    {{topic}}
    {{topic}}
    {{topic}}
    {{topic}}
{% endfor %}
```

Now my output is:

/ / / / / / Home Home Home Home Home Home /database/ /database/ /database/ /database/ /database/ /database/ Database Database Database Database Database Database Log out Log out Log out Log out Log out Log out

How should i do if i want it to output one of each? like:

/Home/database/DatabaseLog out

Comment: just don't repeat `{{topic}}` five times

Comment: I have a html-page where i want to put each element in a specific place, how do i mark where the elements should be then?

Comment: You will need to use CSS/HTML to place the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each time it loops it will iterate over an element in the array and print it so:

```
{% for topic in NAVBAR_LIST %}
    {{topic}}
{% endfor %}
```

Will print each element once.

Following on from your comment you can print out each element where you want like this:

```
{{ NAVBAR_LIST[0] }}
{{ NAVBAR_LIST[1] }}
{{ NAVBAR_LIST[2] }}
{{ NAVBAR_LIST[3] }}
{{ NAVBAR_LIST[4] }}
```

Array keys start at `0` you can access each element with the key.

Comment: Great glad to help, If you plan on doing a lot of work with Python you should read through this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Yes, just had to wait for 10 minutes :)